# Minimal lines for declaring a bunch of similar variables

Tags: java, class, variables, coding-style

I'm making a chess board in Android Studio, and I have a button for each square. 64 variables. How can I initialize all of these at the beginning of my class without taking up 64 lines?

I tried putting the variables in a block of code enclosed by { ... }, but it said I wasn't allowed to.

```
private Button a1;
private Button a2;
private Button a3;
private Button a4;
private Button a5;
private Button a6;
private Button a7;
private Button a8;
```

I would like to have it so that I can click a drop down arrow on the left side of my screen that will make all of these variables disappear until I need to look at them.

Comment: `private Button[][] buttons = new Button[8][8];`

Comment: 64 separate variables is a bad idea since it entirely fails to capture the idea that it's a 8 x 8 board; but if you insist, then there's no reason why one line won't do: ```private Button a1, a2, a3...```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a clever way of linking the buttons in the array with the layout's buttons? That is, something like a nested for loop with buttons[i][j] = findViewByID(R.id.button%d%d, i, j); (EDIT: This is within the onCreate method)

Comment: If you look at my answer, as far as you add the button to the interface/layout prior to adding it to the Array/ArrayList/HashMap, then you will have them linked.

Comment: Why exactly do you need a button for each square of the board? If you're making a chess game, wouldn't it make more sense to make it easier to caculate whether a given piece can move to a particular square?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use an [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in this particular case.

For `ArrayList` you can do:

```java
private ArrayList<Button> a = new ArrayList<Button>();
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    a.add(new Button());
System.out.println(a.get(0));
```

The above gives you flexibility on removing or adding buttons. To keep track of buttons by name instead of index you can use [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

For `HashMap` you can do:

```java
private HashMap<String, Button> a = new HashMap<String, Button>();
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    a.add("Button"+String.valueOf(i), new Button());
System.out.println(a.get("Button0"));
```